# Is there a way of opening Visual Studio Code from MacOS terminal?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am used to opening Jupyter Notebook by simply typing 'jupyter notebook' in the terminal but was wondering whether there is a way of doing the same for for VS Code? (Tried opening it the same way as Jupyter but has not worked). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open VSCode from the terminal but first, you need to add it to the PATH in MacOS

**For zsh shell, run the following**

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

If you use **bash shell** change the first line to
`cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile`

Now you can, open VSCode from the terminal by using the following commands

- To open VSCode with the previous session - `code`
- To open VScode in the current directory - `code .`
- To open a file in VSCode - `code filename`

More command-line options can be found here [VSCode CMD Line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)